# Multiple form in laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, laravel

[image]

I am trying to recreate the above reward form in laravel. It can have multiple rewards which have to be submitted in database. I am currently struggling with jquery to create this view.

Here is my code:

reward Html:

```
<div class="col-md-12 create">
              <div class="create-heading">
                <h1>2. Rewards Offer</h1>
              </div>

              <div class="createbutton">
                <div class="createbutton-show reward-show">
                  <button>Show</button>
                </div>
                <div class="slash">
                  <i>&nbsp;&sol;&nbsp;</i>
                </div>
                <div class="createbutton-hide reward-hide">
                  <button>Hide</button>
                </div>      
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="container col-md-12" >
                <div id="reward-content">
                  <div id="reward-content-form">
                    <div class="reward-contents">

                    </div>

                        </div>
                        <button class="reward-offer-btn"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i><span class="reward-offer-text">Reward Offer</span></button>
                      </div>

                    </div>
```

jquery:

```
var r_id = [0];
var count = 0;
r_id[count];
//var ht = $(".reward-contents").html();
$('.reward-offer-btn').click(function(){
  $( ".reward-contents" ).append( '<div class="reward-add-'+r_id[count]+'"><i class="fa fa-star star-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="reward-name">reward1</span><i class="fas fa-trash-alt trash-icon"></i><i class="fas fa-copy copy-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-cog cog-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i></div><div class="reward-form-"'+r_id[count]+'></div>' );
  count++;
  r_id[count] = count;

});



$('.reward-contents').click(function(){
  $('.reward-contents').append('{!! Form::open(['method' => 'POST' , 'action' => 'UsersController@store' ]) !!}<div class="form-group font-size-80">{!! Form::label('name', 'Reward Name:') !!}{!! Form::text('name',null , ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}</div><div class="form-group font-size-80">{!! Form::label('description', 'Reward Description:') !!}{!! Form::textarea('description',null , ['class' => 'form-control', 'rows'=>'3']) !!}</div><div class="form-group font-size-80">{!! Form::label('points_cost', 'Points Cost:') !!}{!! Form::text('points_cost',null , ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}</div>{!! Form::close() !!}');
});
```

Still working on the jquery.

Comment: you planned submit the reward offers at once?

Comment: yes i want to submit it all at once